# Entity Framework Core : get list from dynamic table with string as parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a dynamic variable that could be the name of every table I have on my database.

Here a example what data I want to get

```
var tableData = _context.Users.ToList();
```

But the `Users` should be passed in as a string.

What I tried:

```
// Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create a DbSet for 'object' because this type is not included in the model for the context.'
var tableData = _context.Set<object>().FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}").ToList();

// Returned -1
var tableData = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}");
```

After I receive the data I call the following function to get the bytes of a `.CSV` file.

```
public byte[] ExportToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    csvWriter.WriteRecords(data);
    streamWriter.Flush();

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

How would I fix this?

Using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.5 (latest)

Comment: `_context.Set` needs an actual type of one of your tables, not `object`. And `ExecuteSqlRaw` just returns the number of rows affected, which is `-1` for `SELECT` statements. You simply can't do it this way, you are going to need reflection. What do you hope to *do* with the data afterwards, if you don't know the exact type?

Comment: I want to create a csv file for each table I got and encrypt it into a zip file and so forth.

Comment: And how do you propose to do that, where is that code? Sounds like you might need the non-generic function `_context.Set(someTypeObjectHere)` but what you do with the results is unclear.

Comment: Well with the result I got from example `var Users = _context.Users.ToList();`

I run this function to get the bytes (csv)

       public byte[] ExportToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
            using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            csvWriter.WriteRecords(data);
            streamWriter.Flush();

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

Comment: You should put that in the question, not in a comment, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to use the non-generic `DbContext.Set` function, and use the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface

```cs
public IEnumerable GetData(Type typeOfTable)
{
    return _context.Set(typeOfTable);
}
```

In EF Core this function is not available, so you will need reflection to call the generic one.

```cs
public IEnumerable GetData(Type typeOfTable)
{
    var mthd = _context.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m =>
        m.Name == "Set" && m.GetParameters().Length == 0);
    var genericMthd = mthd.MakeGenericMethod(typeOfTable);

    return (IEnumerable)genericMthd.Invoke(_context, null);
}
```

You then need to pass that into your CSV function.

It is not correctly handling flushing of the writer. Here is the corrected code, note that the writers are fully disposed, but set to leave the stream open.

```cs
public byte[] ExportToCsv(IEnumerable data)
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, leaveOpen: true))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(data);
    }
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Note that using `ToArray` is inefficient: ideally you would just rewind the stream and pass it back rather than a new `byte[]` array. All the more so if you intend to write it eventually to a file or a web response.

Comment: I receive a error on line `return _context.Set(typeOfTable);` with "0411: The type arguments for method "DbContext. Set TEntity» (string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Ty specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: Given that we have a string of table name, how do we pass that to the parameter `Type typeOfTable`?

Comment: Maybe use `_context.Model.FindEntityType` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imodel.findentitytype?view=efcore-7.0