# How to dynamically set TEntity in DbContext.Set<TEntity>(string name)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, set, dbcontext

I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0 and EntityFrameworkCore. I have the following:

```
var dataSet = db.Set<AgeGroup>(tableType.ToString());

await dataSet.LoadAsync();

var tableData = dataSet.Local.OfType<IReferenceTable>().OrderBy(rt => rt.SortOrder).ToList();
```

Instead of passing the type, such as `AgeGroup`, I would like to pass a variable, such as `model`, to reuse the code with about two dozen types. However, I get an error that I need to pass a type and not a variable.

In ASP.NET and EntityFramework, a type did not need to be passed, such as `var dataSet = db.Set(tableType.ToString());`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core : get list from dynamic table with string as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76196456/entity-framework-core-get-list-from-dynamic-table-with-string-as-parameter)

Comment: You need reflection for this

Comment: Is `_context` a `DbContext`? because I have tried using a couple of different ones and neither recognizes `GetMethods()`.

Comment: If you have a question on that post then comment over there not here. I've made a small correction to it now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a variable as a generic type parameter when using the DbContext.Set(string name) method. However, to resolve this situation;

1. Let's assume the model name is "AgeGroup"
2. Let's get the type of model name
3. Upload the required data
4. List table data

```
string modelName = "AgeGroup";
```

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType(modelName);
var dataSet = (DbSet<IReferenceTable>) db.Set(entityType);
await dataSet.LoadAsync();
```

```
var tableData = dataSet.Local.OfType<IReferenceTable>()
    .OrderBy(rt => rt.SortOrder).ToList();
```

```
await dataSet.LoadAsync();
var tableData = dataSet.Local.OfType<IReferenceTable>()
    .OrderBy(rt => rt.SortOrder).ToList();
```

Comment: `var dataSet = (DbSet<IReferenceTable>) db.Set(entityType);` requires that I specify a type after `db.Set`, such as `db.Set<AgeGroup>`.

Comment: @csharpdev This code only works on EF not EF Core